# TStringAlignGrid from D6 to DelphiXE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Has anyone been able to convert the StringAlignGrid by Andreas Hörstemeier from Delphi 6 (his latest release) to work under Delphi XE?

I have several projects that use StringAlignGrid extensivly and I would rather not convert to another grid if possible.

Steve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source is freely available, so if you need to get this working straight away, you could just attempt to do it yourself.http://www.hoerstemeier.com/files/grid21.zip

I've quickly loaded the source and it's not that hard to do. I've got a version that compiles here, but I don't really have the time to test it. It took me about 3 minutes to get it working, so I suggest you just do what I just did:

- ah_def.inc needs to be changed add XE; Otherwise you'll get a lot of code that's meant for pre-delphi 3. That fixes most of the compiler errors.
- there's a conditional define in ah_def.inc that defines ShortString. If it's defined, you'll get `String` instead of `ansistring`.
- A couple of PString variables that need to be changed to PAnsiString (unless you want to have unicode)
- two PChar's that need to be PAnsiChar.

If you do make it work, don't forget to send your version to Andreas.

Comment: With your suggestions I have been able to compile it but I cannot figure out how to install the component.  If I install AliGridR.pas it says it installs but the icons never show up.  am I missing doing something in XE?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem in the past for another component. Contacting the author was the solution : I received the sources for free accepting a confidentialty agreement.

Comment: He has not updated his website since 2001 and the email address no longer works.  I sent him a message on one of the social networks but I suspect he has moved on and is not interested in this old project anymore.